# Angular Module Federation with multiple repo not working

Tags: javascript, angular, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I've been able to create a monorepo project with several micro frontends without any issues, but I'm struggling to add a micro frontend from a different repo.

Shell:

**webpack.config.js**

```
 new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      library: { type: "module" },
        
      remotes: {
          "mfe1": "mfe1@http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js", //mfe from same repo as shell
          "mfe2": "mfe2@http://localhost:2000/remoteEntry.js", //mfe from same repo as shell
          "mfe-repo": "mfe-repo@http://localhost:4200/remoteEntry.js", //mfe from different repo as shell
      },
```

**sidebar.component.html**

```
<a class="" routerLink="/dandylion/dandylion-overview" routerLinkActive="linkactive" routerLinkActiveOptions="{ exact: false }">
 <span>Dandylion</span>
    </a>
    <a class="home" routerLink="/snafu/snafu-overview" routerLinkActive="linkactive" routerLinkActiveOptions="{ exact: false }">
      <span>Snafu</span>
    </a>
 <a routerLink="/mfe-repo" routerLinkActive="linkactive" routerLinkActiveOptions="{ exact: false }">
      <span>MFE Repo</span>
    </a>
```

**app.routes.ts**

```
 {
      path: 'dandylion',
      loadChildren: () => loadRemoteModule({
          type: 'module',
          remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js',
          exposedModule: './Module'
        })
        .then(m => m.DandylionModule) 
    },
    {
      path: 'snafu',
      loadChildren: () => loadRemoteModule({
          type: 'module',
          remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:2000/remoteEntry.js',
          exposedModule: './Module'
        })
        .then(m => m.SnafuModule) 
    },
 {
      path: 'mfe-repo',
      loadChildren: () => loadRemoteModule({
          type: 'module',
          remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:4200/remoteEntry.js',
          exposedModule: './Module'
        })
        .then(m => m.AppModule) 
    },
```

MFE Repo:

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "mfe-repo",
    publicPath: "http://localhost:4200/"
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },   
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    }
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        library: { type: "module" },
        name: "mfe-repo",
        filename: "remoteEntry.js",
        exposes: {
            './Module': './src/app/app.module.ts',
        },        
    }),
  ],
};
```

**app.routes.ts**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: 'mfe-repo', component: AppComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
];
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { APP_ROUTES } from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES),

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I'm stuck at this for the last 2 days, so if anyone can give a outside check, it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
Happy coding

Comment: I am also stuck with the above scenario, trying to add module federation to a multi repo angular code base and its not working..is there any luck in your side ?

Comment: answered @Prats :) hope it helps!

Comment: LuisPLSP, @Prats, when you guys say it is not working, what is not working? How does it manifest itself?

Comment: I have added module federation to multi repo approach. Unfortunately I am stuck on how to share the state between these separate repos (shell, mfe1, mfe2).

1. Not planned to migrate to Nx Monorepo approach
2. Not planned to publish a NPM package to sharing module

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

We'll, as usual, the problem was a simple code change on the remote/mfe:

Instead of defining the RouterModule as 'forRoot', the correct way to set it was 'forChild'. As easy as that!

MFE Repo:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { APP_ROUTES } from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(APP_ROUTES), // fix is here

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Do you have reference available for above changes  ?

Comment: For others reference https://github.com/Hulk914/moduleFederation project works fine for multi repo using angular-architects module federation

Comment: The answer you gave looks strange. I'm facing the same issue and will try what you gave. But if it works how can you explain it works with forRoot in monorepo?

Answer (score 0):

For me works like that:
`microfrontend1`:
create new module not access `app` module

`webpack.config` -> from `microfrontend1` `module.exports -> exposes`

`'./Module': './projects/mfe1/src/app/flights/flights.module.ts'`

`mf.manifest.json` you should you have something like that

`"frame":"http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.js"`

Shell routing you must have

```
{
path: 'frame',
loadChildren: () =>
  loadRemoteModule({
    remoteName: 'frame',
    type:"manifest",
    exposedModule: './Module',
  })
    .then((m) => m.FlightsModule), !=> m.AppModule
},
```

I how to help this answer. :-)